# Installing ffi 1.9.21 with native extensions on Ruby 2.4.2, Ubuntu 17.10 failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ffi

ffi gem 1.9.21 installed successfully.
I also tried to run these commands but no success.

```
sudo apt install libffi-dev
gem inst ffi
```

This error occurs when I deploy to AWS. The error looks like this.

```
Installing dotenv 2.2.1
Installing request_store 1.3.2
Installing draper 3.0.1

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180207-2245-1bjhja4.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... no
checking for shlwapi.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

  make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
Running autoreconf for libffi
/var/app/ondeck/vendor/bundle/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c/libffi/autogen.sh: line 2: exec: autoreconf: not found
make: *** ["/var/app/ondeck/vendor/bundle/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a] Error 127

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/app/ondeck/vendor/bundle/gems/ffi-1.9.21 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/app/ondeck/vendor/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/ffi-1.9.21/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.21), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.21'` succeeds before bundling. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

Any help will be much appriciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: ffi gem new version 1.9.22 is available. Update to ffi-1.9.22 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 8):

Seems like this issue is due to the ffi latest version, I specified the ffi oldest version in Gemfile `gem 'ffi', '1.9.18'` run `bundle install`  in the console, it fixed my issue.

Comment: @AjayBarot - are you suggesting that this is a bad answer? To fix a blocking deployment issue for example, a fixed version may not be such a bad thing to do.

Comment: @AjayBarot - that wasn't clear from your short comment. I assumed the worst. Based on the info in that page, do you have the correct resolution that you could post as an answer?

Comment: @Phil: I got your point. before that I thought issue was with packages on AWS server. so due to wrong gem dependancy on server,  OP get this kind of error. Before solving gem dependancy I prefer to understand the differences between gem 'version' that mention in first link. But I think that was not the root cause.

Comment: Thanks you. I struggled for more than 2 hours on this.

Answer (score 6):

As stated in [a comment on a relevant issue](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/608#issuecomment-363698071), the workaround is:

```
sudo apt install libffi-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your server

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Ref: [Registered issue](https://github.com/ev3dev/ev3dev.github.io/issues/229)

Please let me know If this not worked.

Comment: I already did that but no success, Still getting the same error.

Comment: Same here. It seems like OP has commented on the ffi gem issue here: https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/608. Looks like the best place to track is https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/607. For now, fixing the gem to 1.9.18 seems to be the only workaround.

Comment: @AndrewSmith: Did you tried the fix which they suggested in these issues?  https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/608, https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/607

Comment: No, I didn't. Looks like the issue at github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/607 is fixed now, although I haven't had time to test it yet.